# Fetch records for today and tomorrow, ignoring weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, if-statement, between

I have just setup the filter below to only retrieve items for today and tomorrow (which works just fine):

```
BETWEEN { fn CURDATE() } AND DATEADD(day; 1; GETDATE())
```

But on Friday I must get Monday's items as well - I am trying to setup an IF statement around this but I am not having any luck at all. Below is an example (that does not work) but I am stumped as to how to write this correctly:

```
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) IN (6)
THEN BETWEEN { fn CURDATE() } AND DATEADD(day; 3; GETDATE())
ELSE BETWEEN { fn CURDATE() } AND DATEADD(day; 1; GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
where (datepart(weekday, getdate()) = 6 and
       datecol between cast(getdate() as date) and cast(getdate() + 3 as date)
      ) or
      (datepart(weekday, getdate()) <> 6 and
       datecol between cast(getdate()as date) and cast(getdate() + 1as date)
      )
```

Note:  I am not a fan of using `between` with date/date times.  Aaron Bertrand has a nice [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) posting explaining this.  `BETWEEN` is safe for dates, so I am leaving the logic as you seem to have specified it.

Comment: Not having luck running the above, when I enter it directly into SQL I get incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'. Also does not work as a filter in MSSQL Studio 2k8, I get function argument count error.